# What is better? Delete and insert or update?

Tags: sql-server, python

I have a python script in which I have to update a column in 67000 rows. The value of the desired column can be unique for each row. I found that inserting 67000 rows takes about 5 seconds but updating takes around 2 minutes! Since I have to update large number of rows and there is huge speed difference I am thinking of deleting the 67k records and inserting fresh. Are there any dangers with this approach that I should be aware of?

Comment: The performance difference could well be in how you are performing the DML statement. Is this running in a loop by any chance?

Comment: Well yeah, of course there are risks. How are you going to "insert fresh"? If there is a primary key on the table, you're going to need to delete everything first. Where are you going to store it? How many things do you think might go wrong in the meantime? Why don't you focus on improving the performance of the update instead of trying to find "clever" ways to buck the traditional way to perform an update? Why is this in a python script and not a stored procedure? Maybe the problem is you're looping and updating one row at a time? Could you share more details about the table and the update?

Comment: @JNK, I am using pyodbc executemany. Checkout https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted for more info.

Comment: What OS are you performing this on?

Comment: `I am using pyodbc` <-- hey look, I found your problem! This thing runs 67,000 individual UPDATE statements. You are barking up the wrong tree. Write an UPDATE statement in a stored procedure that handles these updates using ***set-based*** logic, then have pyodbc call your stored procedure. Bet it doesn't take two minutes then.

Comment: @billinkc Since this post is tagged [tag:sql-server], I'm guessing Windows :-)

Comment: @Colin'tHart ... the python OS could be anything, though. I wonder if that's what bill was requesting.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Obviously the SQL Server instance resides on Windows but they could be using executing python on Linux or Mac. Knowing whether I have to constrain my answers to Windows only solutions is helpful

Comment: what indexes exist on this table? could you please post table structure (including indexes), data, and relevant python code? also, is this part of an application or is it a separate process that runs these updates?

Comment: @billinkc my python code runs on windows.

Comment: Any triggers for update on the table?

Comment: @AndriyM, no triggers

Comment: Insert into another table so drop first table and rename new table

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot more to worry about with a `DELETE`/`INSERT` methodology. From the top of my head:

- Transactions will need to be manually handled. An `UPDATE` is a single operation that is atomic. With `DELETE`/`INSERT` it's possible to have the delete succeed but the insert fail, in which case you have no data. You need to handle this manually and the engine handles the update automagically.
- Foreign keys/references. If you use any data in that table or it's referred to elsewhere, the `DELETE` gets a lot more complicated, as does the `INSERT` with linking back to the correct record from the child table if you dropped the key.
- Log file growth. Depending on your settings, the statement, and the table the 2 operation method could log more to the transaction log.
- Indexes. It's a lot more expensive to D/I through indexes than to update. Could also lead to fragmentation in the indexes more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for this list. I am aware of the first and one option I was thinking is rename the key column on the old data set, insert new data and then delete the old one. Of course there would be a mess to clean up manually if this one has issues as well. I am not worried of the second option since I don't have constraints at db level. Third one is a good point and fourth one I need to educate myself on :). I wanted to vote you up but it needs a reputation of 15 :(

Comment: @user3885927 You don't have constraints? Do you not care about your data?

Comment: ......poor data

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course there are risks. How are you going to "insert fresh"? If there is a primary key on the table, you're going to need to delete everything first. Where are you going to store it? How many things do you think might go wrong in the meantime?

Stop using pyodbc's cursor functionality to perform an update. This is calling 67,000 individual UPDATE statements, and probably sending them as individual batches too, with all the overhead associated with that. It shouldn't be any surprise that this is slow.

Instead, if you are updating the whole table, figure out the ***single*** UPDATE statement you need to affect the whole table in one go. This is what SQL Server is optimized to do, rather than inspect one row, update it, inspect another row, update it, and on and on. When you need to do grocery shopping, do you drive to the grocery store, buy eggs, drive home, then drive back to the grocery store, buy milk, drive home, then drive back to the grocery store, buy bread, and so on? Of course not. This is what your ptodbc executemany thing is doing.

And yes, this can be done even if some rows will get different values. e.g.

```
UPDATE dbo.foo
  SET sound = CASE animal WHEN 'cow' THEN 'moo' WHEN 'cat' THEN 'meow' ... END
```

Wrap that in a stored procedure, and have Python call the stored procedure. Then you can focus on real problems instead of problems you created yourself by poor tech choices. :-)

Comment: Viewing the documentation for pyodbc, it looks like the `.executemany()` method will execute once for each statement so you're right - there are 67,000 executions of the update.

Comment: This is one of the options I considered prior to posting this question. I just couldn't figure out easy way to pass an array to stored procedure using pyodbc. Besides that there is a limit of 2100 values with pyodbc. I have 2 values for the where condition and one for setting the column value so I have to do this 90+ times any ways. Seems there are options to send xml and parse it back but I am not sure if that works well with pyodbc. Any ideas?

Comment: Push your updates to a table using your fast insert mechanism and then do a set based update

Comment: @billinkc, thank you! This seems similar to my idea (see my comment to JNK) of renaming the key for the old data set, inserting new data set and deleting the old data set. However inserting into a separate table and updating from there sounds cleaner. I will try this out and see the overall performance.

Comment: @billinkc, I used this idea and it works great! Could you put your idea as an answer so I can accept it?